# why jquery plusslider doesn't work in google chrome but works in firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

i am using jquery plusslider but the problem is it works fine in firefox but the slider doen't work in google chrome. also whenever i use slidertype as fader the slider works fine in both but i want to user slidertype as slider and its not working.what is the problem. thanks in advance for any help/suggestion and your time. thank you..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').plusSlider({ 
        sliderEasing: 'easeInOutExpo', // Anything other than 'linear' and 'swing' requires the easing plugin
        paginationBefore: true,
        createArrows: true,
        width: 1920,
        height:580,
        sliderType: 'slider', // Choose whether the carousel is a 'slider' or a 'fader'
        displayTime: 5000
    });
```

Comment: put html code here. or you missing in last `});`

Comment: no that's not the problem ... its closed in my actual code. sorry for the mistake but it doesn't hab effect.

Comment: @user108 found the problem .... in chrome <div style="width:0px; left: 0px;"> but whereas in firefox the same <div style="width:0px; "> and the value of left changes accordingly to the slider. how do i fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

See **[Edit](http://jsfiddle.net/h2je6/)** It will work IN Chrome

```
$('#slider').plusSlider({
        sliderEasing: 'easeInOutExpo', // Anything other than 'linear' and 'swing' requires the easing plugin
        paginationThumbnails: true,
        sliderType: 'slider' // Choose whether the carousel is a 'slider' or a 'fader'
    });​
```

You missing in Last `});`

Comment: think i didn't understand your edit or i am missing some very simple things. can you please elaborate. i think u saw a missing }); in my code. if it's the case i want to say it's not missed in my actual code.all the braces are closed.

Comment: actual i will not see your comment before i will post. so now working or not ?

Comment: i will try your code in my chrome it's working but see in console give any error or not. you put css all check this also.